# How to check if all elements of a list of dictionary are same?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of nested dictionary and I want to check if the values of nested dictionaries of the list are same or not

Eg :

```
    [{area1 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
    {area2 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'CH',4:'IN'}},
    {area3 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
    {area4 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',4:'IN'}},
    ]
```

Here since different area has different values hence
output: should be **false** and also I want to **print** which areas have different values i.e area1 , area2 , area 4

Here below since all area have same values hence the output **true**

```
    [{area1 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
     {area2 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
     {area3 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
     {area4 : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
    ]
```

Is there any easy way to do so ?

Comment: Please show case your attempts.

Comment: Is the position in the list important? i.e. would having `area1` after `area2` be different from having `area2` after `area1`? Are the indexes for the dictionary important?

Comment: @MatsLindh no the indexes are not important .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each `dict` values into tuples and put them in a `set`. This will collapse duplicates for you:

```py
def areValuesIdentical(src):
    s = set(tuple(tuple(i.items()) for i in list(d.values())) for d in src)
    return len(s) == 1

s=[{'area1' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
    {'area2' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'CH',4:'IN'}},
    {'area3' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
    {'area4' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',4:'IN'}},
    ]
        
print(s,areValuesIdentical(s))

s = [{'area1' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
     {'area2' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
     {'area3' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
     {'area4' : {1:'USA',2:'CA',3:'IN',4:'CH'}},
    ]

print(s,areValuesIdentical(s))
```